# Where can I store data as a System Service?

Tags: java, android, android-source, mkdir, system-services

I programmed a system-service and it tries to create a directory to save some data. The dir that I chose was `/.myServiceData`.
When I try to run it I get this error: `mkdir /.ethNode: read-only file system`.

Where can I store my data in the system-service on android?

-UPDATE:
I now tried to `getFilesDir()` in the system-service, and it also throws an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data directory found for package android
```

Comment: Post some code?

Comment: @DarShan I dont think this will help you much: `Geth.newNode("/.myServiceData", nodeConfig);`. Im just passing a string of a path to another library. And the code for the library is pre-compiled c++, so can't really show the code.